# How to add a <br/> after each result, but not last result?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my partial code:

```
while($row = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
     echo $row['row_name'];
}
```

How can I make it so it will add a break tag after each result, but not the last result?

Comment: Simple answer is that most languages have a 'join' operation on strings that will do this for you.

Answer (score 16):

Put the output into an array, then join the array with [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$rows = array();
while($row = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
     $rows[] = $row['row_name'];
}
echo implode('<br/>', $rows);
```

Comment: this is a terrible overhead you are addding. Especially if there are many rows

Answer (score 6):

You could do this. No arrays or counters.

```
if($row = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    do {
        echo $row['row_name']
    } while($row = $db->fetch_array($query) && print("<br />"));
}
```

Comment: thanks. You'll find a lot of similar nifty tricks throughout the the wordpress source and any major javascript framework.

Comment: more interested in php tricks (even tho i must say I don't like the fact that this solution needs a double redundant call to fetch_array() )

Comment: there are no redundant fetch_array() calls? it's a do while loop. The first call checks whether there is data to be fetched, if so the result of that call is passed into the loop with a second call to fetch_array().

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($idx = 0; $row = $db->fetch_array($query); $idx++)
{
     if ($idx > 0) { echo "<br/>"; }
     echo $row['row_name'];
}
```